# How to feed data in fullcalendar with laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I'm trying to feed the fullcalendar event property with `json` data from controller but is is not showing in the calendar, and I think I'm doing it well, but it's not. Please see my code below:

**Controller**

```
public function getCalendar(){
    $allBookings = Booking::with('itemsBooked')->get();
    $bookings = json_encode($allBookings);

    return view('admin.calendar.index', compact('bookings'));
}
```

**view**

```
<div id="jCalendar"></div>
```

**Fullcalendar setup**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jCalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: '{{ $bookings }}',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        theme: true,
        themeSystem:'bootstrap3'
    })
});
```

Note: The fullcalendar setup is located at the bottom of the view, so I can use the `$bookings` variable there. But it is not showing even if I have data in my database.

**Problems:**

1. The data is not showing in the calendar.
2. How can I customize what data will be shown in the calendar.

**Updates**

console.log output:

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;employee_name&quot;:&quot;John Doe&quot;,&quot;customer_name&quot;:&quot;Steeves&quot;,&quot;booked_code&quot;:&quot;BC-E1D7C6&quot;,&quot;pax_number&quot;:30,&quot;extension_of_rental&quot;:0,&quot;additional_room&quot;:0,&quot;start_time&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 08:00:00&quot;,&quot;end_time&quot;:&quot;2018-02-25 05:00:00&quot;,&quot;total_price&quot;:&quot;6500&quot;,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;booked&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-23 00:38:14&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 10:01:56&quot;,&quot;items_booked&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:5,&quot;category&quot;:&quot;pool&quot;,&quot;item&quot;:&quot;day_swimming&quot;,&quot;item_price&quot;:&quot;6500&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 10:07:53&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 10:07:53&quot;,&quot;pivot&quot;:{&quot;booking_id&quot;:1,&quot;item_booked_id&quot;:5,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 10:07:53&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 10:07:53&quot;}}]},{&quot;id&quot;:13,&quot;employee_name&quot;:&quot;Kristine Anna Mesa&quot;,&quot;customer_name&quot;:&quot;John Doe&quot;,&quot;booked_code&quot;:&quot;BC-5582E5&quot;,&quot;pax_number&quot;:30,&quot;extension_of_rental&quot;:0,&quot;additional_room&quot;:0,&quot;start_time&quot;:&quot;2018-02-25 12:00:00&quot;,&quot;end_time&quot;:&quot;2018-02-25 11:59:59&quot;,&quot;total_price&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;pending&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 23:52:44&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2018-02-24 23:52:44&quot;,&quot;items_booked&quot;:[]}]
```

Comment: Calling `json_encode` on `$allBookings` seems to be doing more than we ask of it. It's replacing quotes with corresponding HTML Entity Do `$bookings = $allBookings->toJson()`  [to serialize `$allBookings`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections).

Comment: @OluwafemiSule It has the same output

Comment: Quick fix here: `JSON.parse('{{ $bookings }} '.replace(/(&quot;)+/g, '"'))`. But I won't advised this approach. What server are you using to serve?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I'm using apache server.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule The data is still not showing in the calendar. Note: I have `start_date` and `end_date`, and `created_at` and `updated_at` in my database

Comment: Oops! The (Event Object Schema)[https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/] should have a compulsory `start` and `title` field and an optional `end` field. You'll need to alias `start_time` and `end_time` to `start` and `end` respectively. How you compute `title` is left to you discretion

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Alright. Can you edit your answer below with that explicitly? So I can mark a check for your answer in case it solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As-is, `events` is set to a string of bookings instead of a JSON array of objects.

Remove the quotes to the interpolated `$bookings` value.

```
events: {!! $bookings !!}
```

**Update**

Events in `$bookings` have to be consistent at least with [Event Object Schema](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

```
public function getCalendar()
{
    $columns = [
        'start AS start_time',
        'end AS end_time',
        'title AS customer_name'
    ];
    $allBookings = Booking::with('itemsBooked')->get($columns);
    $bookings = $allBookings->toJson();

    return view('admin.calendar.index', compact('bookings'));
}
```

Thanks to your comment @Jonjie, I saw this in [Laravel documentation about Blade templating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade).

> **Displaying Unescaped Data**
>
> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
> ```

Comment: I removed my quotes and now, my calendar is not showing as well.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log({{ $bookings }})` before the calendar setup and add the output to your question if it's not so much text? If it is, put it in a pastebin and share

Comment: It is working now, but please edit `JSON.parse('{{ $bookings }} '.replace(/(&quot;)+/g, '"'))` to `JSON.parse('{!! $bookings !!})` so it won't escape the characters

Comment: If so. I think JSON.parse may not be required because `{!! !!}` statements are not passed through PHP htmlentities function